# How to convert pdf document to ocr pdf document

Tags: python, ocr

I have a problem where I need to convert a pdf document to OCR pdf document just like how Adobe Acrobat works. I have tried that using ocrmypdf module, but somehow it is not working. I am using python 2.7. Any other modules is also appreciated.

```
import logging
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import time
import shutil

path="D:\Nikhil Scraping\Pdf all processing"

for filenames in os.listdir(path):
     print (filenames)
     filename=filenames.split('.')[0]
     print (filename)
     input_path=os.path.join(path,filenames)
     outputfile=filename+"_OCR.pdf"

     cmd=["ocrmypdf","--output-type", "pdf", input_path, outputfile]
     logging.info(cmd)
     proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
     result = proc.stdout.read()
```

Error Shown :

```
1-9-US 118137380VP1.pdf
1-9-US 118137380VP1

Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "D:\Nikhil Scraping\Pdf all processing\pdf_ocr_working.py", line 19, in <module>
     proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
     File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
     File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

while i am using the same code in python 3.7, it is working fine but no output file is generated.

Also it is successfully working in mac OS, i don't know why windows is showing this errors.

[My Code Approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G13Ky.png) [Error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz5b9.png)

Comment: Maybe you are facing this because of space in your folder name. Try another folder without space.

Comment: No, I have tried pushing it to another another folder which doesn't have spaces, even that it is showing the same error

Comment: try changing path from `path="D:\Nikhil Scraping\Pdf all processing"` to format of `path="D:\\NikhilScraping\\Pdfallprocessing"` (escap space and double \\ for path) or `path=r"D:\Nikhil Scraping\Pdf all processing"` (raw string),

Comment: @dkb No, even this is also not working. as far i know there is no problem with the path variable the problem lies in the ocrmypdf module, if there is a problem in the path then it wont even enter into for loop, it might show error something like this `for filenames in os.listdir(path):
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:`

Answer (score 0):

You are joining all filenames here instead of one filename

```
input_path=os.path.join(path,filenames)
```

Use this code instead

```
input_path=os.path.join(path,filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
But this will not work. I am using filename just to change for the name of the downloaded file, 

if I print the input_path (if filenames is kept) : D:\Nikhil Scraping\Pdf all processing\1-9-US 118137380VP1.pdf     

but if I print the input_path (if filename is kept) : D:\Nikhil Scraping\Pdf all processing\1-9-US 118137380VP1 , which is not a file, so it won't